# Check service availability from java

Tags: java, sockets

How can I check service using java? I found [this article](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/109.html), but it is only for checking hostname.

My question is how can I check is service on port x running, ex: `myhostname:8080` or `myhostname:8099` , I might be running service n or p on those ports but it would be visible trough web if I do it manually, how can I achieve same effect in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That snippet sends a ping, which you can't manipulate to achieve what you want. Just [open a socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) and catch any exceptions.

```
bool success = true;
try {
  (new Socket(host, port)).close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  // unknown host
  success = false;
} catch (IOException e) {
  // io exception, service probably not running
  success = false;
}
```

If you need to detect which service is running, then you need to read the first bytes sent and compare them to what you know each service should send. This might require a few passes back and forth.

Comment: socket variable should be outside of the try block in order to be close in the finally block.

Comment: @h3xStream I don't have a java compiler on me to test with, but are you sure that's necessary?

Comment: If the socket constructor throws an exception, you can't close it, so simply `new Socket(host, port).close();` inside the `try` block would do it.

Comment: @Greg You beat me to it, though there's the one annoyance that `close()` can throw an `IOException` so having the `close` in the try could complicate things if you want to distinguish between a failure on opening the socket and a failure on closing it. Regardless, using `finally` is unnecessary here.

Comment: @Greg, @Laurence Thanks, I've made that change.

Answer (score 3):

Since your services are web, you might want to add a verification of the response code.

```
boolean available = false;
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://yourdomain/").openConnection();
    conn.connect();

    if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200)
        available = true;
}
catch(IOException e) {
}
finally {
    if(conn != null)
        conn.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just attempt to connect to the socket.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("myhostname");
Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 8099);
```

If that doesn't thrown an exception then the host is accepting connections on that port. If it isn't you'll typically get a [ConnectException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just attempt to use the service and deal with the exceptions as they arise. There's generally no point in testing any resource for availability prior to using it. What if it was available when you tested and not when you used it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets to do this.

```
new Socket("localhost", 8080).getInputStream()
```

Surround that with a try catch block and you have a solution.