# Check service availability by service name in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, port

According to following article, I can create a simple socket in Java to check the availability of a service. However, a port number is needed to check the service.

[Check service availability from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652293/check-service-availability-from-java)

However, if I only have the service name defined in /etc/services, how can I check the service availability? Do I have to get the port number by service name at first? Reference to the following question:

[Port to Service Name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393012/port-to-service-name-in-java)

I am expecting some more native way to make OS to translate the service name for me rather than translate it by myself in Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to parse `/etc/services` I fear you're looking at some JNI or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) implementation of [getservbyname()](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_getservbyname.htm).

I would perhaps start by parsing the services file, and look at the native implementation if this isn't really good enough. Abstract/wrap it so swapping one solution for another isn't so painful.